# How to use bootstrap's dropdown on table cell (td)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I have a simple html table layouted with bootstrap:

```
[...]
<td data-toggle="dropdown" class="tag dropdown-toggle">
<span class="number">Employee1</span>
<ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="#">to nightshift</a></li>
</ul>
</td>
[...]
```

But when I click on the cell, the dropdown does not appear.
How can I let the dropdown appear like it is done here?

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp

Do I need listen to *td.click* manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will be helpfull for you problem. You have missed parent dropdown class and add the below css in you stylesheet.

html

```
<tr class="dropdown">
    <td class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">John <span class="caret"></span>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
```

css

```
.open ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```